# Stores dynamically columns into SQL database

Tags: java, swing, oracle11g, nullpointerexception

I am working on a basic desktop Java application. I have a "more" buttons and when I click on it a new line of `JTextField` and `JDateChooser` appears. All I want is to store these lines into database. How can I implement it?

Here is my code.

**MemberDao.java**

```
public boolean isExist(CachedRowSet crs, String colName) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData meta = crs.getMetaData();
    int columns = meta.getColumnCount();
    for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
        if (colName.equals(meta.getColumnName(x))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**InsertMember.java**

```
if(evt.getSource()==more){
    try {
        if(MemberDao.getInstance().isExist(crs,"mem_familyname")){
            System.out.println("found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not found");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }            
}
```

But this code gives me a `NullPinterException`

[image]

Comment: where you are getting NPE? share the logs..

Comment: Collect all data into  Arraylist<>  and store into database after storing a database make a empty arrylist